# How to control title font in UINavigationBar title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, title

I have navigation bar controller in which i want to display text. But the text is not the same every time.  It will be minimum of 5 and maximum of 60 characters.  I want all of the characters to be visible.  How can I set min and max font size for UINavigation Bar title?

Thanx

Comment: strange the question is down voted.

Comment: agree.  maybe the run-on sentence.  we mostly concern ourselves with the grammar of artificial languages here.  i've edited your q. and up voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the titleView on the UINavigationBar.  You can set it to a UILabel with any of the normal UILabel settings.

Answer (score 2):

here is the answer

```
UILabel *bigLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
bigLabel.text = @"1111111122222233333344444455555556666777888899999000000";
bigLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
bigLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
bigLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
bigLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[bigLabel sizeToFit];

self.navigationItem.titleView = bigLabel;
```